# NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: <app information> has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud

I'm getting the above error while trying to work with iCloud.  It works on all the other developer devices without this problem but I can't seem to fix it.

I have looked at other posts which recommend deleting and reinstalling the app, restarting xcode, deleting profiles from the phone, deleting files from the app itself and none of these things have worked.  I know my iCloud is available and it registers that my app is there and using the service.  The phone is not jailbroken and building to iOS7.

Any suggestions on how to get rid of this error would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same problem. But it only happened in iOS 7. It runs well in iOS 6. By the way, I'm running in iOS 7 simulator. Is it the cause of the problem ? (Because I have no device installed iOS 7.)